# How to setup new Gmail Hangouts

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I recently heard about Google Hangouts at Gmail, and I accidentally ignored “Try it now” while it asked me to try Google Hangouts. Is there any way to enable the new features back on Gmail if I ignored the "try it now"?

I already refereed [here](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?p=upgrade&rd=1), but I can’t see "Try the new Hangouts" below my account picture.

i also cross checked by clearing cache,cookies,history of my browser and tried with fresh installation of browser with all updated plugins.

Here is my chat window screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the drop-down menu you have when you click on your picture? It should be the first option, above the current status options — _Available_, _Busy_, _Invisible_.

Comment: Also, if you have a Google+ account, you can try the new Hangouts there, where it’s the default (and only) option for chat.

Comment: @Alex i already tried out in google+ and wished for gmail too friend ,i added screen cut of my pic in my question

Comment: Try signing out from Gmail and emptying your browser’s cache/delete cookies. Also, sign out from Chat first, as well.

Comment: Long shot: it could also be related to the fact that you don’t have the voice/video plugin installed.

Comment: @Alex tried it and in my browser already configured with it ,i cleared cookies/cache and all temp data and even tried with new firefox installation it failed :(

Comment: I just adden an answer that includes the current content of the referred link in the question (https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?p=upgrade&rd=1).

Answer (score 1):

From [Hangouts in Gmail - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?hl=en)

> Turn on Hangouts in Gmail
>   ---   You can try the new Hangouts from the menu in Google Chat.
>
> 1. Open [Hangouts in Gmail](http://gmail.com).
> 2. At the top of your Google Chat list, click your profile photo.
> 3. Click Try the new Hangouts.
> 4. Gmail will refresh, and you can start using Hangouts.

Comment: usually for gmail users it will does the work,it wont work for custom domain users of gmail where the hangouts were restricted by the domain administrator